# Drop-down menu, how to make the role issued by pressing Python Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I started working on a Discord bot in Python, I ran into the problem that I can't find information on how to make the role be issued using the menu
The code I wrote:
`

```
class Dropdown(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options = [

            discord.SelectOption(label="role1", description="Крутая роль", emoji=""),

            discord.SelectOption(label="role2", description="Богатая роль", emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="role3", description="Игровая роль", emoji=""),
        ]

        super().__init__(
            placeholder="Меню",
            max_values=1,
            min_values=1,
            options=options
        )
    
    async def callback(self, inter: discord.MessageInteraction):
        await inter.response.send_message(f"Вы выбрали роль {self.values[0]}")


class DropdownView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_item(Dropdown())


@bot.command()
async def role(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Выберите роль:", view=DropdownView())
```

`

I tried to find it in the sources, even if I could find something, it didn't work.

Comment: Use the `id` of the role as the `value` of your `SelectOption`, use `get_role` to get the role, and `add_roles` to add it to the user. There's no info on how to issue roles from menus because this isn't related to dropdowns at all. Just get & add the role in the callback.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

## Options on Certain Roles

There are various ways of doing this, but I'd suggest giving the value to each option based on that role's id. You can get the id by clicking the `...` button on the role and copying the id. You can then use

```py
from discord.utils import get

role = get(inter.guild.roles, id=role_id)
```

Before we can continue I need to mention that the interaction received is not a [`MessageInteraction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=ui%20select#discord.MessageInteraction) but a [`Interaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=ui%20select#discord.Interaction), so we can access the guild attribute that it has.

With that in mind, putting it all together with the code you have would be:

```py
from discord.utils import get

class Dropdown(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options = [

            discord.SelectOption(label="role1", value=str(roleid1) ,description="Крутая роль", emoji=""),

            discord.SelectOption(label="role2", value=str(roleid2), description="Богатая роль", emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="role3", value=str(roleid3), description="Игровая роль", emoji=""),
        ]

        super().__init__(placeholder="Меню",options=options)
    
    async def callback(self, inter: discord.Interaction):
        await inter.user.add_roles(get(inter.guild.roles, id=int(self.values[0])))
        await inter.response.send_message(f"Вы выбрали роль <@&{self.values[0]}>")


class DropdownView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_item(Dropdown())


@bot.command()
async def role(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Выберите роль:", view=DropdownView())
```

Also note that the default values for `max_values`, and `min_values` is 1, so you can skip them. Look [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=ui%20select#discord.SelectOption) for more information

## All Roles

You can use the [RoleSelect](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=roleselect#discord.ui.RoleSelect) class to get the roles automatically. You can then on the interaction use it's [values](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=roleselect#discord.ui.RoleSelect.values) property to get a list of roles that have been selected. All of it would look like this

```py
import discord.ui


@bot.command()
async def role(ctx):
    view = discord.ui.View()
    role_select = discord.ui.RoleSelect(placeholder="Меню")

    async def role_select_callback(inter):
        await inter.response.send_message(f"Вы выбрали роль {role_select.values[0]}")
    
    role_select.callback = role_select_callback
    view.add_item(role_select)
    await ctx.send("Выберите роль:", view=view)
```

to add a role to the user that sent this command all you have to do is change the callback function so that it adds the role to the person that interacted with the message

```py
import discord.ui


@bot.command()
async def role(ctx):
    view = discord.ui.View()
    role_select = discord.ui.RoleSelect(placeholder="Меню")

    async def role_select_callback(inter):
        await inter.user.add_roles(role_select.values[0])
    
    role_select.callback = role_select_callback
    view.add_item(role_select)
    await ctx.send("Выберите роль:", view=view)
```

Comment: There are all server roles in the list, but I need to be given roles whose id I will specify myself.

Comment: @HattoriClaus I added the part on how to do that. Also note that passing an empty string to an emoji will cause an error because it's an invalid emoji

Comment: Thank you, everything is clear and explained in detail, everything worked out.

Comment: @HattoriClaus Thank you, make sure you accept this answer if you are satisfied with it, so this question gets marked as complete